# Почему видео в модальном окне продолжает играть после закрытия окна?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, почему видео в модальном окне на сайте www.симультики.рф продолжает играть даже после закрытия модального окна, либо выдает ошибку? Видео доступно по кнопке "Привет!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вообще-то в яве не разбираюсь, но люди добрые подсказали, надо здесь

```
$('.popup__close').click(function() {
    p.css('display', 'none');
})
```

добавить это

```
$(this).next()[0].pause();
```

и заработало!))

Comment: @Aviko, рад, что вам помогли:)

Answer (score 2):

При закрытии модального окна, оно скрывается, не очищая и не изменяя содержимого. Из-за этого видео остаётся невидимым и продолжает играть.

Comment: Хорошо, как же "очистить" и "изменить" содержимое?:)

Comment: @Aviko, что-бы ничего особо не менять, то так:

     var a=$('блок-с-видео>обьект-с-видео');
     a.attr('src',a.attr('src'));

Из-за изменения одного из атрибутов, обьект пересоздастся и, следовательно что-бы запустить видео, на него нужно будет нажать еще раз.

Answer (score 2):

мдям

```
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Это сильный ход!

ну и далее по списку каждый раз писать

```
<!--Скрипт попапа-->
                    <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
        p = $('.popup__overlay')
$('#popup__toggle').click(function() {
    p.css('display', 'block')
})
p.click(function(event) {
    e = event || window.event
    if (e.target == this) {
        $(p).css('display', 'none')
    }
})
$('.popup__close').click(function() {
    p.css('display', 'none')
})
                    </script>
                    <!--X-->
```

не нужно, можно и один раз написать.

```
$('.popup__close').click(function() {
    p.css('display', 'none')
})
```

Ну а вот тут нужно стирать внутрянку, чтобы видео дальше не проигрывалось.

```
$('.popup__close').click(function() {
     $(p).remove() // ну типа того, но второй раз видео уже не откроется :)
    })
```

**//upd** ну ведь немного подумать нужно.

```
<div class="popup__overlay">
<div class="popup" id="f_vid">
<a href="#" class="popup__close">X</a><video width=420 controls>
<source src="freeman.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
<source src="freeman.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
</video>
</div>

 $('.popup__close').click(function() {
         $("#f_vid").remove() // ну типа того, но второй раз видео уже не откроется :)
        })
```

Сделать для нужного окна ID и по этому ID удалить элемент.

Comment: $(p).remove() поставил, ничего не меняется

Answer (score 1):

Задайте `visibility: hidden;` вместо `display: none;`

Comment: а где менять, в файле стилей или в функции?

Answer (score 1):

Как, допустим, я делал у себя (правда с prototype.js).

```
<a href="youtube_link_for_example" class="video">link_text</a>
<script>
handler = new VideoHandler();
$$(document).getElementsByClassName('video').each(function(){
handler.bind(this);
});
var VideoHandler = Class.create();
VideoHandler.prototype = {
  initialize: function() {
    this.modalWindow = new ModalWindow();
    this.modalWindow.setParams({params:...});
    this.modalWindow.onClose(this.onClose);
  },
  show: function(){
    this.modalWindow.setTemplate(VideoHandlerTemplate);
    ...
  }
  bind: function(element) {
    that = this;
    element.observe("click", function(event){that.show();});
  },
  onClose:function(){
    $('modalWindowContent').update("");
  },
  ...
 };
</script>
```

Здесь не привожу много кода, сколько там, просто хотелось показать, что тоже существовали проблемы с видео. Скрывать никакими методами не получалось, звук всё равно шёл. Проблему решил в этом случае удаление кода шаблона со вставленным видео, а при новом нажатии - заполнении с нуля.